# No available formula with the name "php7.1-imagick"

Tags: php

I'm recently updated to php 7.1, however im getting this warning whenever i do `php -v`

I'm running mac Os El Captain

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.18/lib/php/20160303/imagick.so' -
>   dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.18/lib/php/20160303/imagick.so,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.18/lib/php/20160303/imagick.so' -
>   dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.18/lib/php/20160303/imagick.so,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/opt/php71-imagick/imagick.so' -
>   dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php71-imagick/imagick.so, 9): image not found in
>   Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/opt/php71-imagick/imagick.so' -
>   dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php71-imagick/imagick.so, 9): image not found in
>   Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in
>   Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

I tried doing

`brew reinstall -s php71-imagick`

and i get this

> No available formula with the name "php@7.1-imagick".

Any suggestions on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

Following this tutorial helped

https://jason.pureconcepts.net/2016/09/upgrade-php-mac-os-x/

i pretty much just removed php71

and did

`curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.1`

open the terminal and

`open .bash_profile`

and add the line

`export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH`

and now we have this

> PHP 7.1.13 (cli) (built: Feb  1 2018 13:38:42) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2017 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017
>   Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.1.13, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans Users-iMac-2:~ poweruser$ clear

Works fine NOW !